# List data structure in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

While in a for loop I tried to append values queried from a data-frame in Pandas. I used something like:

```
n = df.loc[(df["B"] > 50) & (df["C"] == 900), "A"]
my_list.append(n)
print("my_list is", my_list)
```

and it printed:

```
my_list is [21.5, 23.5, 24.5, 12    24.5
Name: b, dtype: float64]
```

It seems that all values in the list except for the last one are of the same format, but the last one is of a different format, ie., `24.5 Name: b, dtype: float64`. It was probably because that I queried the last value using a different method than the other values.

The output looks like this:

```
[21.5, 23.5, 24.5, [24.5]]
```

How can I make the values the same format so that the output looks like `[21.5, 23.5, 24.5, 24.5]`?

---

Edit:

```
    Timestamp               X   Y   B   C       Type    Id
0   2000-10-26 10:08:27.060 18  14  0.0 24.5    medium  18
1   2000-10-26 10:39:24.310 18  13  1.0 24.0    low     18
2   2000-10-26 11:50:48.190 18  14  1.0 23.5    medium  18
```

Comment: because the last value in your list seems to be a dataframe, or rather, a series. It isn't useful to talk about "formats". Your list contains *objects*. It seems that the first three objects are of the `float` type, and again, the last one seems to be of the `pd.Series` type.

Comment: @nil can we see the data?

Comment: Hi @juanpa.arrivillaga I tried `n.astype('float')` , `n.to_numeric` and `pd.to_numeric(n).astype('float')` and nothing changed

Comment: @nilsinelabore of course not, those all return `pd.Series` (or if used on a dataframe, a `pd.DataFrame`). You probably want something like `n = df.loc[(df["B"] > 50) & (df["C"] == 900), "A"].item()` Or if you *expect* more than one item, just sue `my_list.extend(n.tolist())`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you it worked:) Could have accepted your solution if you'd like to answer it below

Comment: @ombk I added an example of df in Edit:)